# Function error with my Solidity map(int,string) while using javascript to return values to html.

Tags: javascript, html, solidity

I can't get my labels to update with a JavaScript function call to my Solidity smart contract function. I'm trying to create an (integer, string) map in solidity to display values in HTML with a button click. For some reason **threatActor.getActor(1,function(error, result)** returns NULL.

Could someone take a look and help me in the right direction? Thank you.

HTML Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <script src="/home/zachary/employee-eth/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="container1">

        <label for="labels" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Labels: </label>
        <input id="labels" type="text">

        <label for="aliases" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Aliases: </label>
        <input id="aliases" type="text">

        <label for="roles" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Roles: </label>
        <input id="roles" type="text">

        <label for="goals" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Goals: </label>
        <input id="goals" type="text">

        <label for="resource_level" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Organization: </label>
        <input id="resource_level" type="text">

        <label for="sophistication" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Sophistication: </label>
        <input id="sophistication" type="text">

        <label for="primary_motivation" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Primary Motivation: </label>
        <input id="primary_motivation" type="text">

        <button id="buttonSet">Submit Threat</button>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="container1"><button id="buttonGet">Get Threats by ID</button></div>
        <div id="container2"><input id="getId" type="text" value="1"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container2">

        <h1>Actor Attributes</h1>

        <label for="actorID" class="col-lg-2 control-label">ID: </label>
        <label id="actorID_d" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Empty</label>

        <label for="labels" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Labels: </label>
        <label id="labels_d" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Empty</label>

        <label for="aliases" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Aliases: </label>
        <label id="aliases_d" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Empty</label>

        <label for="roles" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Roles: </label>
        <label id="roles_d" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Empty</label>

        <label for="goals" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Goals: </label>
        <label id="goals_d" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Empty</label>

        <label for="resource_level" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Organization: </label>
        <label id="resource_level_d" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Empty</label>

        <label for="sophistication" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Sophistication: </label>
        <label id="sophistication_d" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Empty</label>

        <label for="primary_motivation" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Primary Motivation: </label>
        <label id="primary_motivation_d" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Empty</label>

    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        }
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        var threatActorContract = web3.eth.contract([
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_labels",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_aliases",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_roles",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_goals",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_resource_level",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_sophistication",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "_primary_motivation",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addActor",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "actors",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "labels",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "aliases",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "roles",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "goals",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "resource_level",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "sophistication",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "primary_motivation",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "countActors",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_key",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getActor",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]);

        var threatActor = threatActorContract.at("0xcf5f9fb59f9b22810c50a9158b393388c492c258");
        console.log(threatActor);

        $("#buttonSet").click(function() {
            threatActor.addActor($("#labels").val(), $("#aliases").val(), $("#roles").val(), $("#goals").val(),
            $("#resource_level").val(), $("#sophistication").val(), $("#primary_motivation").val());
        });

        $("#buttonGet").click(function() {

            threatActor.getActor(1,function(error, result) {

            if(!error)
                {
                    document.getElementById("#labels_d").innerHTML = result[0];
                    document.getElementById("#aliases_d").innerHTML = result[1];
                    document.getElementById("#roles_d").innerHTML = result[2];
                    document.getElementById("#goals_d").innerHTML = result[3];
                    document.getElementById("#resource_level_d").innerHTML = result[4];
                    document.getElementById("#sophistication_d").innerHTML = result[5];
                    document.getElementById("#primary_motivation_d").innerHTML = result[6];
                    console.log(result);
                }
                else {
                    console.error("ERROR!");
                }
        });

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Solidity Smart Contract Code:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
    contract ThreatActors {

        uint actorAmount = 1;

        struct Actor{
            string labels;
            string aliases;
            string roles;
            string goals;
            string resource_level;
            string sophistication;
            string primary_motivation;
        }

       Actor[] public actors;


    function addActor(string _labels, string _aliases, string _roles, string _goals, string _resource_level, string _sophistication, string _primary_motivation) public
        {
            Actor memory actor = Actor(_labels, _aliases, _roles, _goals, _resource_level, _sophistication, _primary_motivation);

            actors.push(actor);

            actorAmount++;
        }


    function getActor(uint _key) view public returns (string, string, string, string, string, string, string) {
        return (actors[_key].labels, actors[_key].aliases, actors[_key].roles, actors[_key].goals, actors[_key].resource_level, actors[_key].sophistication, actors[_key].primary_motivation);
    }

    function countActors() view public returns (uint) {
        return actors.length;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you call `getActor`  soon after you called `addActor`?
If so, the transaction for `addActor` may not mined yet, thus the actor hasn't been added to the contract.

Try again with by initializing  at lease one actor in the contract and see what happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you say that it returns NULL, you mean that the `result` in the callback function is NULL, correct?  If so I have a few guesses but nothing concrete:

1. Your input is somehow translated wrong when passed to the function.  It expects a uint256 and you give the number literal 1.  I have to assume this should work but I usually stick to wrapping my numbers in BigNumber and have never used a literal (but again, why wouldn't it work).
2. You are using strings in Solidity.  In order to have absolute control over my struct sizes and memory usage I nearly never use dynamic arrays.  They definitely have uses, but usually a `mapping` can do what a dynamic array can do, and 32 characters (`bytes32`) is more than enough for most cases a `string` would be used in.  I'm not exactly sure where this could be causing an issue but I figured I'd point it out.
3. Maybe your version of web3 is wrong.  I know some versions are fine with simply calling the function, while others prefer call / send to be used (depending on whether it's a constant function).  If you're using 1.0 this could be the case as [seen in the docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12).