# the mapping struct return null by web3

Tags: struct, null, mapping, solidity, web3js

Now I try to do the solidity to save the struct data, and retrieve the data by mapping string in web3 interface.

Now I've finished the data saving part, and I can get the data in my Remix API, but if I wanna get the data by web3, it'll return null as following:

[image]

the version of the web3 is 1.3.4. I once tried whether I can return the data in the function of saving data and it worked, thus I guess that the data isn't shared by functions in web3...

and I found out this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656813/function-error-with-my-solidity-mapint-string-while-using-javascript-to-return), but I still can't get the solution.

the following is the code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage{
    string b = "calculation a";
    
    struct UserInfo {
        string time;
        uint emission;
    }
    mapping (string => UserInfo) public users;

    function saveData(string memory input_time, string memory input_source, string memory input_mycalculate, uint input_material) public{
        users[input_source].time = input_time;
        if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(input_mycalculate)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(b)))
            users[input_source].emission = input_material * 3 / 2;
        else
            users[input_source].emission = input_material * 5 / 2;
    }
    
    function search(string memory input_source) public view returns (UserInfo memory) {
        return users[input_source];
    }
}
```

and the following is the js code to show the data:

```
contract.methods.search(input_company).call({from:web3.eth.defaultAddress})
  .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        companyResultLineChart.innerHTML += result[0] + result[1]
  })
```

Comment: First of all, I can't find ```methods.search()``` in web3 documents. Then I can't find ```input_company``` in your solidity code. Could you please tell me version of your web3 and how does ```methods.search()``` work?!

Comment: my web3 version is `1.3.4`. And the `methods.search` means that I wanna utilize the function of `search` in the solidity.

Comment: `input_company` is the input element of the html, when I input the company I wanna search, it will use the function `contract.methods.search()` to grab the mapping struct of the `input_company`

Comment: by the way, I deployed the contract by **remix**, and I use the **ganache** as the blockchain network in port 7545.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be an timing issue. It is a asynchronous JavaScript code so you have to use ".then" or await. In Your code example you are using ".then". I used saveData function with "60sec", "test_src", "calc", "10" for testing purpose. So below code:

```
console.log("------ before then ------ ")
let innerHTML = "HTML "
contract.methods.search("test_src").call().then((result) => {
   console.log(innerHTML)
   innerHTML += result[0] + result[1] 
   console.log(result)
   console.log(innerHTML)
   
})

console.log("------ after then ------ ")
```

will type in console:

```
------ before then ------ 
------ after then ------ 
HTML 
[ "60sec", "25" ]
HTML 60sec25
```

Code with await:

```
console.log("------ before await ------ ")
let innerHTML2 = "HTML "
let result_async = await contract.methods.search("test_src").call();
console.log(innerHTML2)
innerHTML2 += result_async[0] + result_async[1] 
console.log(result_async)
console.log(innerHTML2)
console.log("------ after await ------ ")
```

will type in console:

```
------ before await ------ 
HTML 
[ "60sec", "25" ]
HTML 60sec25
------ after await ------
```

Comment: Which you mean is that the data return the result, before it read it from contract, right?

Comment: Yes, that code wanted to process or use result before data was read from blockchain.

Comment: if you use the `await`, don't forget to declare the `async` function to use it within it !